# Device events has duplicating patient records

Tags: openfda

It seems that in the https://open.fda.gov/device/event/ the patients have duplicated records.

```
  "patient": [
    {
      "sequence_number_treatment": [
        ""
      ],
      "patient_sequence_number": "1",
      "date_received": "19920310",
      "sequence_number_outcome": [
        "1. R"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sequence_number_treatment": [
        ""
      ],
      "patient_sequence_number": "1",
      "date_received": "19920310",
      "sequence_number_outcome": [
        "1. R"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Reported a bug in the project  [GitHub](https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/80)

Answer (score 1):

If you could, please submit a bug report in our GitHub and we'll take a look.

Comment: Reported a bug in the project  [GitHub](https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/80)